Primefaces dataTable not rendered correctly after change page
I created a notifications tray. Firstly its structure was coded using p:tabView tag and two tabs, each tab with a p:dataTable inside. When I try to change the page of one of the p:dataTable, the new page is not rendered correctly and paginator dissapears. I thought that the problem was the p:tabView component and I replaced the p:tabView structure to nested h:panelGroup. In two ways problem persists.
This is the initial state of the page:

When I press the page 2, the dataTable is rendered like this:

Now, if I press the "Actualizar" button (update button), now the page 2 is rendered correctly:

I don't understand this behavior. This is the previous code using p:tabView tag:
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{notificacionesBean.updateNotificacionesButton()}"/>
</f:metadata>
<p:scrollPanel id="localPanel" widgetVar="localPanel" mode="native" >
    <div style="margin-left: 14px;">
        <h3>
            Notificaciones
        </h3>
    </div>
    <p:tabView id="bandejas" activeIndex="#{notificacionesBean.activeTab}" dynamic="true" widgetVar="bandejasViewTab" >
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" update="bandejas" listener="#{notificacionesBean.loadTab}" />
        <p:tab title="Bandeja de Entrada (#{notificacionesBean.unread})" >
            <f:facet name="title">
                <i class="pi pi-inbox" />&nbsp;
                <h:outputText value="Bandeja de Entrada (#{notificacionesBean.unread})" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-refresh" value="Actualizar" actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.updateNotificacionesButton()}" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.marcarComoLeidoMulti()}" update="bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" process="inbox @this" value="Marcar como leído(s)" icon="fa fa-regular fa-envelope-open" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.marcarComoNoLeidoMulti()}" update="bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" process="inbox @this" icon="pi pi-envelope" value="Marcar como no leído(s)" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.eliminarMulti()}" update="bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" process="inbox @this" icon="pi pi-trash" value="Eliminar" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:dataTable id="inbox" rows="25" emptyMessage="Usted no tiene notificaciones nuevas" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" var="msj" value="#{notificacionesBean.inboxMsjs}" selection="#{notificacionesBean.notifSeleccionadas}" rowKey="#{msj.idMsj}" widgetVar="inbox" rowIndexVar="indexMsj" selectionMode="multiple" >
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{notificacionesBean.notificacionSeleccion}" />
                <p:column selectionBox="true" style="text-align: center;" width="30" />
                <p:column headerText="Remitente" style="width: 300px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.abreviarCampo(msj.sender.nombre.replace('/', ' '), 37)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Asunto" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.abreviarCampo(msj.asuntoEstilizado(), 200)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Fecha" style="width: 55px;">
                    <center>
                        <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.fechaEstilizada(msj)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 66px;">
                    <center>
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.eliminarUno(msj)}" update="globalForm:bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" icon="pi pi-trash" title="Eliminar" />
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.cambiarEstatusLeido(msj)}" update="globalForm:bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" icon="#{notificacionesBean.iconEnvelope(msj)}" title="#{notificacionesBean.titleEnvelope(msj)}" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>    
        <p:tab title="Papelera">
            <f:facet name="title">
                <i class="pi pi-trash" />&nbsp;
                <h:outputText value="Papelera" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.moverAinbox()}" update="bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" process="trash @this" icon="pi pi-inbox" value="Mover a bandeja de entrada" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.marcarComoLeidoTrash()}" update="bandejas" process="trash @this" icon="fa fa-envelope-open" value="Marcar como leído(s)" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.marcarComoNoLeidoTrash()}" update="bandejas" process="trash @this" icon="pi pi-envelope" value="Marcar como no leído(s)" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:dataTable id="trash" rows="25" emptyMessage="La bandeja esta vacía" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" var="msj" value="#{notificacionesBean.trashBinMsjs}" selection="#{notificacionesBean.notifSeleccionadasTrash}" rowKey="#{msj.idMsj}" widgetVar="trash" rowIndexVar="trashMsj" selectionMode="multiple" >
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{notificacionesBean.notificacionSeleccionTrash}" />
                <p:column selectionBox="true" style="text-align: center;" width="30" />
                <p:column headerText="Remitente" style="width: 300px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.abreviarCampo(msj.sender.nombre, 37)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Asunto" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.abreviarCampo(msj.asuntoEstilizado(), 200)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Fecha" style="width: 55px;">
                    <center>
                        <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.fechaEstilizada(msj)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 66px;">
                    <center>
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.moverAinboxMsj(msj)}" update="globalForm:bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" icon="pi pi-inbox" title="Mover a bandeja de entrada" />
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.cambiarEstatusLeido(msj)}" update="globalForm:bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" icon="#{notificacionesBean.iconEnvelope(msj)}" title="#{notificacionesBean.titleEnvelope(msj)}" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</p:scrollPanel>

This is the current code using nested h:panelGroup:
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{notificacionesBean.updateNotificacionesButton()}"/>
</f:metadata>
<p:scrollPanel id="localPanel" widgetVar="localPanel" mode="native" >
    <h3>
        Notificaciones
    </h3>
    <h:panelGroup id="bandejas">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.setActiveTab(0)}" update="bandejas">
                        <div class="#{notificacionesBean.inboxClass()}">
                            <i class="pi pi-inbox" style="margin-right: 10px;" />Bandeja de Entrada (#{notificacionesBean.unread})
                        </div>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.setActiveTab(1)}" update="bandejas">
                        <div class="#{notificacionesBean.trashClass()}">
                            <i class="pi pi-trash" style="margin-right: 10px;" />Papelera
                        </div>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{notificacionesBean.activeTab == 0}">
            <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-refresh" value="Actualizar" actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.updateNotificacionesButton()}" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.marcarComoLeidoMulti()}" update="bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" process="inbox @this" value="Marcar como leído(s)" icon="fa fa-regular fa-envelope-open" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.marcarComoNoLeidoMulti()}" update="bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" process="inbox @this" icon="pi pi-envelope" value="Marcar como no leído(s)" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.eliminarMulti()}" update="bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" process="inbox @this" icon="pi pi-trash" value="Eliminar" />
            <br/>
            <p:dataTable id="inbox" rows="25" emptyMessage="Usted no tiene notificaciones nuevas" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" var="msj" value="#{notificacionesBean.inboxMsjs}" selection="#{notificacionesBean.notifSeleccionadas}" rowKey="#{msj.idMsj}" widgetVar="inbox" rowIndexVar="indexMsj" selectionMode="multiple" >
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{notificacionesBean.notificacionSeleccion}" />
                <p:column selectionBox="true" style="text-align: center;" width="30" />
                <p:column headerText="Remitente" style="width: 300px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.abreviarCampo(msj.sender.nombre.replace('/', ' '), 37)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Asunto" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.abreviarCampo(msj.asuntoEstilizado(), 200)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Fecha" style="width: 55px;">
                    <center>
                        <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.fechaEstilizada(msj)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 66px;">
                    <center>
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.eliminarUno(msj)}" update="globalForm:bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" icon="pi pi-trash" title="Eliminar" />
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.cambiarEstatusLeido(msj)}" update="globalForm:bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" icon="#{notificacionesBean.iconEnvelope(msj)}" title="#{notificacionesBean.titleEnvelope(msj)}" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{notificacionesBean.activeTab == 1}">
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.moverAinbox()}" update="bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" process="trash @this" icon="pi pi-inbox" value="Mover a bandeja de entrada" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.marcarComoLeidoTrash()}" update="bandejas" process="trash @this" icon="fa fa-envelope-open" value="Marcar como leído(s)" />
            &nbsp;
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.marcarComoNoLeidoTrash()}" update="bandejas" process="trash @this" icon="pi pi-envelope" value="Marcar como no leído(s)" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p:dataTable id="trash" rows="25" emptyMessage="La bandeja esta vacía" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" var="msj" value="#{notificacionesBean.trashBinMsjs}" selection="#{notificacionesBean.notifSeleccionadasTrash}" rowKey="#{msj.idMsj}" widgetVar="trash" rowIndexVar="trashMsj" selectionMode="multiple" >
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{notificacionesBean.notificacionSeleccionTrash}" />
                <p:column selectionBox="true" style="text-align: center;" width="30" />
                <p:column headerText="Remitente" style="width: 300px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.abreviarCampo(msj.sender.nombre, 37)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Asunto" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.abreviarCampo(msj.asuntoEstilizado(), 200)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Fecha" style="width: 55px;">
                    <center>
                        <h:outputText value="#{notificacionesBean.fechaEstilizada(msj)}" style="font-weight: #{msj.fontWeight()}; display: block;" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 66px;">
                    <center>
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.moverAinboxMsj(msj)}" update="globalForm:bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" icon="pi pi-inbox" title="Mover a bandeja de entrada" />
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{notificacionesBean.cambiarEstatusLeido(msj)}" update="globalForm:bandejas globalForm:menItNotif" icon="#{notificacionesBean.iconEnvelope(msj)}" title="#{notificacionesBean.titleEnvelope(msj)}" />
                    </center>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:scrollPanel>

This is the code of "Actualizar" button (update button):
public void updateNotificacionesButton() {
    inboxMsjs = mensajesService.findMensajesBandejaEntrada(usuario.getIdUsuario(), (short) 1);
    unread = inboxMsjs.size();
    PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("globalForm:bandejas");
}

I am using this in my project:

Primefaces 14.0.4
Payara 6.2024.5
OpenJDK 17.0.2
Jakarta 10.0

I'll appreciate any hint about what is happening. Thanks.

This is tough to try and debug without a PrimeFaces Test reproducer.

The problem was a conflict with the following f:metadata tag:
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{notificacionesBean.updateNotificacionesButton()}"/>
</f:metadata>

After changing page the previous listener was fired. This listener method had another programatic ajax update that generated a conflict with the internal ajax update of the p:dataTable. So I adjusted my code to be able to remove the f:metadata tag.
